# Can't compile with Android Studio 1.3, gradle says a resource was already defined

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Since I updated to Android Studio 1.3, I'm running into a very weird issue. When I try to launch my apps, it says me that :

"Gradle 2.4 requires Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 (or newer) but project is using version 1.0.0. Please use Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 or newer."

When I click on "Fix plugin version and sync project", it changes this in my build.gradle files

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
}
```

to this :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
```

But I cannot launch my app, because of this resource (in my sw600dp/config.xml file) :

```
<item name="is_tablet" type="bool">true</item>
```

It says that this resource is already defined, in the auto-generated file "values-sw600dp-v13/values.xml" :

```
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:.../src/main/res/values-sw600dp/config.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <item name="is_tablet" type="bool">true</item>
</resources>
```

(It says, when I open this file, that "Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited").

If I comment, in the sw600dp/config.xml file, the resource, it works, but it worked before, it should not say that it has already been defined ! And it does that in all of my apps !

I already tried to :

- Delete the line in the auto-generated file; of course, it creates the line automatically and it still can't compile.
- Input "./gradlew clean build assemble" in the console. What it did was to download "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip", and it ended with :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- I also tried to do "File > Invalidate Caches/Restart"

None of this worked !

What can I do ?

(I'm using a MAC)

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: try to clean your project and rebuild again

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to do that as well, I did clean and rebuild and it still didn't worked :(

Comment: ok than just take backup of your code and try with deleting .idea folder and all .iml files. and just rebuild and run again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused because of changes to how AAPT crunches resources, now it fails if there are identically named resources in any library that you may have included in the project (only .aar dependencies can contain resources).

The solution is to find where the conflict is coming from and exclude it from the project.

Comment: Thanks. You were right, "is_tablet" was already defined in a library after all !

Comment: If it's something you rely on and want to use in multiple library modules internally, the simplest route is to make sure to add a prefix to the resource based on the library name, to avoid clashing names. This is what google play services do as well, and the framework itself.

Comment: ...and exclude it from the project.... I'm experiencing the same situation... can you please tell me how did you do this excluding thing... thanks!